# Drawing a comprehensible table

Tags: tables

I have a 2 column document format. I am interested to draw a specific table. My problem is that my table is big a little bit, That is why I tried first to draw it in a 1 column document format. But when I reduced its size using the command `\resizebox` in order to be drawn only in a 2 column format, it became very small and the values into the table becomes not understandable. So how to draw a comprehensible table in a two-column format document? Any help will be very appreciated:)

You can find my code below:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{center}
    \resizebox{9.5cm}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | | l | l | l | | l | l |}
    \hline
    $\Delta$ & 0.001 & 0.01 & 0.1 & 0.5 & 1\\
    \hline
    $D_s (L=2)$ & $4.17 \times 10^{-8}$ & $4.17 \times 10^{-6}$ & $4.17 \times 10^{-4}$ & $ 0.01$ & $ 0.042$\\
    \hline
    $D_s (L=8)$ & $1.04 \times 10^{-8}$ & $1.04 \times 10^{-6}$ & $1.04 \times 10^{-4}$ & $ 2.6 \times 10^{-3}$ & $ 0.01$\\
    \hline
    $D_s (L=16)$ & $5.2 \times 10^{-9}$ & $5.2 \times 10^{-7}$ & $5.2 \times 10^{-5}$ & $ 1.3 \times 10^{-3}$ & $ 5.21 \times 10^{-3}$\\
    \hline
    $D_s (L=32)$ & $2.6 \times 10^{-9}$ & $2.6 \times 10^{-7}$ & $2.6 \times 10^{-5}$ & $ 6.51 \times 10^{-4}$ & $ 2.6 \times 10^{-3}$\\
    \hline
    $D_s (L=64)$ & $1.3 \times 10^{-9}$ & $1.3 \times 10^{-7}$ & $1.3 \times 10^{-5}$ & $ 3.255 \times 10^{-4}$ & $ 1.3 \times 10^{-3}$\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \end{center}
```

Comment: It would be easier if you could provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Why are you using the `multicols` environment in a twocolumn document? I suggest you just put the `tabular` environment inside a `table*` environment so that it spans both columns.

Comment: Why don't put along the entire width of the page? we can't force something impossible.

Comment: Place the table outside of the `multicols` environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't do something like this. Here's my complete code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % only to generate some text
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1] % Some text
\end{multicols}
\begin{table}[h]
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|*{6}{l|}}
    \hline
    $\Delta$ & 0.001 & 0.01 & 0.1 & 0.5 & 1\\
    \hline
    $D_s (L=2)$ & $4.17 \times 10^{-8}$ & $4.17 \times 10^{-6}$ & $4.17 \times 10^{-4}$ & $ 0.01$ & $ 0.042$\\
    \hline
    $D_s (L=8)$ & $1.04 \times 10^{-8}$ & $1.04 \times 10^{-6}$ & $1.04 \times 10^{-4}$ & $ 2.6 \times 10^{-3}$ & $ 0.01$\\
    \hline
    $D_s (L=16)$ & $5.2 \times 10^{-9}$ & $5.2 \times 10^{-7}$ & $5.2 \times 10^{-5}$ & $ 1.3 \times 10^{-3}$ & $ 5.21 \times 10^{-3}$\\
    \hline
    $D_s (L=32)$ & $2.6 \times 10^{-9}$ & $2.6 \times 10^{-7}$ & $2.6 \times 10^{-5}$ & $ 6.51 \times 10^{-4}$ & $ 2.6 \times 10^{-3}$\\
    \hline
    $D_s (L=64)$ & $1.3 \times 10^{-9}$ & $1.3 \times 10^{-7}$ & $1.3 \times 10^{-5}$ & $ 3.255 \times 10^{-4}$ & $ 1.3 \times 10^{-3}$\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[2-3] % Some text 
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

And here part of the result

[image]

Comment: And (a comment to the OP) do your readers a favor, loose almost all of those lines in the table. This is a *grid*, not a datatable. The lines makes it harder to read.

Comment: @daleif Lines are part of MWD of the question's author and this is a problem of alignment and positioning of a table in a document to two columns.

Comment: Which is why I mentioned it was a comment to the OP. We also spend at lot of time here telling people that what they are doing might not be such a good idea. This is often just a byproduct of seeing people's code.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer :) I appreciate it very much

Comment: And if your table is very wide consider put it in `landscape` mode using a package like `sideways` or `rotating`.